# Is there a way to infer generic types in Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, generics, jakarta-mail

I want to create a generic method for sending emails with attachments, I was thinking about using something like this:

```
public class MailAttachment<T> {

    private String attachmentName;
    private T attachment;

    public MailAttachment(String attachmentName, T attachment) {
        super();
        this.attachmentName = attachmentName;
        this.attachment = attachment;
    }
    //Getters and setters

}
```

Later, send the generic type and let Java decide in compilation time the instance type sent. But the compiler adds an error saying that it needs to be cast to the correct type  (File, DataSource, InputStreamSource).

```
   @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

 public void sendHtmlMail(Mail mail, MailAttachment<?> attachment) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
                    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);

                    helper.setTo(mail.getTo());
                    helper.setSubject(mail.getSubject());
                    helper.setFrom(host);
                    message.setContent(mail.getContent(), "text/html");
                    if (attachment != null) {    
                        //Casting error 
                   helper.addAttachment(attachment.getAttachmentName(), attachment.getAttachment());
                    }
                    mailSender.send(message);
                } catch (MessagingException | MailException e) {
                    logger.error("Error sending email: ", e);
                }
            }).start();
        }
```

So I had to use a workaround to validate and cast to the correct type, something like this:

```
if (attachment.getAttachment() instanceof DataSource) {
    helper.addAttachment(attachment.getAttachmentName(),
                        (DataSource) attachment.getAttachment());
} else if (attachment.getAttachment() instanceof File) {
    helper.addAttachment(attachment.getAttachmentName(),
                        (File) attachment.getAttachment());
} else if (attachment.getAttachment() instanceof InputStreamSource) {
    helper.addAttachment(attachment.getAttachmentName(),
                        (InputStreamSource) attachment.getAttachment());
}
```

**So, I was wondering if there is a better way to check this kind of stuff using only this method while keeping the generic type in the parameter?**

Comment: Perhaps you need a `<T extends SomeValidAttachmentType> void sendHtmlMail(Mail mail, MailAttachment<T> attachment)`  where  the type argument of `T` is what your mail message is expecting.

Comment: But, what about if I later need to send other attachment types (Datasource, File, InputStreamSource). Do I have to overload the method to receive those types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an interface Attachable:

```
interface Attachable {
  void attach(Helper helper);
}
```

and then implement this for the various types:

```
class DataSourceAttachable implements Attachable {
  String name;
  DataSource dataSource;  // Initialize in ctor.

  void attach(Helper helper) {
    helper.addAttachment(name, dataSource);
  }
}

// etc, for other types
```

Then there is no need for generics:

```
public void sendHtmlMail(Mail mail, Attachable attachable) {
  // ...
  attachable.attach(helper);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: You could make it generic and construct it with a `BiConsumer<String, T>`.

Comment: @shmosel why not just use a `Consumer<Helper>`, though?

Comment: You're saying the attachment class is altogether unnecessary? I guess that's true, unless there's additional functionality we're not seeing.

Comment: I agree with Andy Turner, the goal here is to eventually attach an Attachable to the MimeMessage. It is the attachable that is responsible and must dictate the way it gets attached. Otherwise, will have to have a catch-all helper the checks what kind of instance you passed and specify for each predefined subclass how to attach it. The downside is that if you introduce a new attachement type, then you have to go to your helper and introduce a new - if instance of -> then do this else do that etc.